# Visual Studio 2015 unrecognized error in Windows Web Services Framework

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I see the following error with Visual Studio 2015 (Tried both community and professional edition). 
Wrote a simple Visual C++ CosoleApplication which has "printf("Hello World\n");".

1. Debug with Platform "x86" Compile and step through Works.
2. Debug with Platform "x64" Compiles but when it runs it throws this error.

Code is simple with following lines:

```
// ConsoleApplication1.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
#include "stdafx.h"


int main()
{
    printf("Hello World \n");
    return 0;
}
```

My desktop has following configuration:
OS: Windows 7 Enterprise  64-bit version
Anti-Virus: McAfee Anti-virus software running; Can't disable that.
Firewall: ON (Can't disable that for security)

**Question:** Stepping through the code with (Debug x86 platform) works. Why "Debug x64 platform" does NOT work ?

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Thanks
gshant

Comment: I uninstalled the whole package, restarted desktop and reinstalled with no effect.

Comment: Looks like no one has faced similar issues! Could someone from Microsoft help? Support lines asks for $499 to start a conversation for this.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same trouble.  This is what I did.

1. Go to Project, Project properties.
2. Select Application Tab and make note of what framework you are using.  For me it was 4.5.2.
3. Use the pull down to select a different Framework.  At the bottom there is an option to install additional Frameworks.
4. After the web page opens, select the Framework you previously noted and download the Development Pack.
5. Close Visual Studio and install the Development Pack.

This worked for me when I selected x64.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for sharing it. I am using Visual Studio 2015 and this project is just a "Console Application". I went to Properties->General tab and ".Net Target Framework Version" is not enabled and does not show a version. The help on that showed it is valid only with "Common Language Runtime support" enabled. I did try to enable that but still this field does not show up. I will look further into it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have both the x86 and x64 .NET Core runtimes installed.

https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows

Answer (score 0):

This answer deals with using IIS 7 to debug.  I have not checked it with IIS Express.

If your web application is 32-bit (x86), you need to run IIS Manager and:

- Look at the "Basic Settings" of your web site.  Check what IIS
  application pool your project is using.
- Look at the "Advanced Settings" of this application pool and ensure
  that "Enable 32-bit applications" is True.

Answer (score 0):

This was a firewall issue for me. I'm not sure the exact root cause, but I found stopping my firewall resolves this. If I find the exact root cause, I'll update my answer so firewall exception rules can be written.

I believe the issue is when you are debugging it is actually using the remote debugger still under the hood (connecting x86 Visual Studio to an x64 process, etc) and a firewall can block this.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to go:

Project -> Properties -> Build -> Prefer 32-bit enabled

with Platform target -> "Any CPU".